# Communication between Client and Server using Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

Okay this is a revised question from earlier today, I have included code to help explain the problem. I am sending two messages from the client to the server. The server then picks the messages up and processes them. The server finally attempts to send a message back to the client(please note in the server code "testmessage"), it is here I am having problems. Either I am not recieving the message at the client side or sending it incorrectly from the server side.

```
public class ClientConnection {

String address, language, message;
int portNumber;
Socket clientSocket = null;

public ClientConnection(String lan, String mes, String add, int pn) throws IOException{
    address = add;
    portNumber = pn;
    language = lan;
    message = mes;
}
public String createAndSend() throws IOException{
    // Create and connect the socket
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    clientSocket = new Socket(address, portNumber);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));     

    // Send first message - Message is being correctly received
    pw.write(language+"\n"); 
    pw.flush(); 
    // Send off the data  

    // Send the second message - Message is being correctly received
    pw.write(message); 
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    // Send off the data

    // NOTE: Either I am not receiving the message correctly or I am not sending it from the server properly.
    String translatedMessage = br.readLine();       
    br.close();
    //Log.d("application_name",translatedMessage); Trying to check the contents begin returned from the server.
    return translatedMessage;
}
```

Server Code:

```
public class ServerConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    // Delete - Using while loop to keep connection open permanently.
    boolean status = false;
    while( !status){
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // Delete - Working as of here, connection is established and program runs awaiting connection on 4444
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));     
        String language = br.readLine();
        String message = br.readLine();
        // Test - Works
        System.out.println(language);      
        // Test - Works
        System.out.println(message);
        // Delete - Working as of here, both messages are passed and applied. Messages are received as sent from client.
        TranslateMessage tm = new TranslateMessage();
        String translatedMessage = tm.translateMessage(language, message);

        // NOTE: This seems to be where I am going wrong, either I am not sending the message correctly or I am not receiving it correctly..
        // PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
        // Send translation back 
        System.out.println(translatedMessage);
        // pw.write(translatedMessage+"\n"); 
        pw.write("Return test"); // Test message!
        pw.flush(); 
        // Send off the data 
        pw.close();
        br.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
}
```

The code is a bit of a mess and I can see a few duplicates, I have commented where I feel the problems occour.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is returned by the readline in the client? is it a null?

Comment: No its a String, though in this example It should be "String test" sent from the server.

Comment: I'd still stick a \n on the `pw.write("Return test\n")` just to eliminate it as an issue.

Comment: I did Jim but still to no avail. Perhaps a new day will yield better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using BufferedReader.readLine() to read the response from the server, but in the test case you are sending a string that is not terminated with a \n or \r\n, so it will not get the line as far as I can tell from the docs...

```
public String readLine()
            throws IOException

Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Returns:
    A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached
```

An additional suggestion...

When writing request response protocols like this I would not rely on line endings to terminate the requests or responses. Typically I would use either a fully formatted JSON string, or my preference is for a binary protocol where all requests and response are prepended with a binary count (usually 4 bytes bigendian/network byte order). Then the client and server reads the 4 bytes then reads the number of bytes that follow. This handles the packet fragmentation that typically happens over network connections, also it helps avoid DOS attacks by malicious users sending long strings that never terminate.

In Java you can use ByteBuffer.order() to handle bigendian numbers.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your comment, if you look just above I was using sending a variable with \n however it was not working either.

Comment: Oh I see you are closing the printwriter before doing the readline in the client,that may not be good as they are using the same socket.

Comment: I tried moving the pw.close and the android application I running froze. hmmmm

Comment: Did you add a `\n` to the test string you are sending, it will freeze waiting to read the entire string upto the \n.

Comment: Also I don't think it is necessary to close the printwriter or the bufferedreader if you just close the socket, those will be closed also I think.

Comment: Okay Jim, I shall try this now.

Comment: You know what i think the problem may be somthing to do with how I pass the recieved message back though the application. Which is an entirely new problem. 

I am stumpped!

Comment: Are you getting something on the client returned by the readline now? Try putting a print after the readline and see what you get.

Comment: Hi Jim, I dont suppose you are able to get an android app to send and recieve messages. Nothing fancy, just somthing that works lol.

Comment: I have several Java client and servers talking to each other, but none of the Java clients are actually Android, although I suspect your problem is not an Android specific issue. Getting client server comms going is always tricky. If you are using text and a request/response have you considered using http as the transport and jetty or similar as the server? That way all the complex communications are done for you.

Comment: I would love to use HTTP but as I have been discussing on a similar forum, I am unsure how to even begin using HTTP to send messages. Sockets seemed such a clear choice, lets say I change to http is there a simple example of sending and recieving messages around the net you could recommend. I am at the point where I am furiously tapping keys but to no avail.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thanks for everything Jim... The application is working a charm! You may notice that I neglected to close the socket on the client side.......

I would still love to here your take on how I could achieve the same results using HTTP.

Thanks again!

Comment: What O/S are you running on the server side? I can package up a simple JETTY based server that'll run on pretty much anything Java runs on, and a sample Java client, can't test on Android, but it'll be regular Java.. can you use apache httpclient libs on android?6

Comment: Take a look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld and see if it makes any sense to you, that would be the minimum jetty configuration to accept web requests, it gets more complicated from there, but not too hard. In your case the requests are pretty simple, and I'm sure android has a simplified way to send http requests.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I am going to have a look in a bit. You may see me here again sometime soon ;) Thanks again!